# Deeplink play console error, manifest issue?

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking, google-play-console

I am using deep links in my apps and it was working till now without problems.

In the deep links section (Play console) - App configuration it shows an issue to my link.
It says:

```
FIX MANIFEST ISSUES
ACTION_VIEW attribute failed
Add an ACTION_VIEW intent action attribute to the intent filter in the manifest of your app
```

I created the action view like from the documents on the first version months ago:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
...
</intent-filter>
```

Like said, it's still there and the links were working for months.
Currently I am only redirected to the app on the google play.

Anyone faced this issue?

I've tried my code and tested everything, it should work.
I've uploaded a new app version to see if it will fix the error.